# Form action pass correct text values according to submit button clicked

Tags: html

My code is

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1">
    <input type="text" name="t2" id="t2">
    <input type="submit" name="s1" id="s1" value="Submit1" onclick='this.form.action="p1.php";'>
    <input type="submit" name="s2" id="s2" value="Submit2" onclick='this.form.action="p2.php";'>
</form>
```

Now I want, if I click on submit1 p1.php should open and I can only access value of text1 and not text2.

Similarly, if I click on submit2 p2.php should open and I can only access value of text2 and not text1.

The pages are openning but I can access both the values ie t1 and t2

I only want to do it with html no js and jquery and I need to make only one form.
NO separate forms allowed.

Comment: Have you tried to use one form and one php script ? You'll check in your php script which submit button is clicked with a test like this : if(isset($_POST['s1']))

Comment: What if you just never declare `$_POST['t1'];` on the p2.php ? Or you can just use if(isset($_POST['t1'])). Or use a GET to get the URL and see if you are on p1 or p2 and according to this select what value should be taken (t1 or t2)

Comment: yes u are correct but im suppose to do it the way i described above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hy sam,

Your question look like wrong may be you are asking to submit all form values in different action using two submit button in a single form.

may be this code will help you to submit values in different form action

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1">
<input type="text" name="t2" id="t2">
<input type="submit" name="s1" id="s1" value="Submit1" formaction="p1.php">
<input type="submit" name="s2" id="s2" value="Submit2" formaction="p2.php">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attribute `formaction` on the submit button to change the current action of your form, without using JS. See [formaction spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-formaction). In case you need to support older browsers like IE9- you can simply use [webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#Forms) to polyfill it:

```
<script>
if(!('formAction' in document.createElement('input')){
    webshim.polyfill('forms');
}
</script>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1">
    <input type="text" name="t2" id="t2">
    <input type="submit" name="s1" id="s1" value="Submit1" formaction="p2.php">
    <input type="submit" name="s2" id="s2" value="Submit2" formaction="p2.php">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use javascript, the only solution that I can think of is to use two HTML forms.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1">
    <input type="submit" name="s1" id="s1" value="Submit1" onclick='this.form.action="p1.php";'>
</form>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="t2" id="t2">
    <input type="submit" name="s2" id="s2" value="Submit2" onclick='this.form.action="p2.php";'>
</form>
```

Comment: i need to make only one form

Comment: You can use CSS to style the two forms so that they appear as one in the browser.